# Catch-22 with creating a pan gesture recognizer as a constant?

Tags: swift, object-initializers, xcode6.3

I have a custom subclass of UIView. It has a pan gesture recognizer that I've set up as a required constant:

```
let dragger: UIPanGestureRecognizer
```

It's a constant because it's created once at initialization of the view and persists for the lifetime of the view.

In the view's designated initializer, `init(coder)`, I want to create my pan gesture recognizer and wire it up. However, Under Xcode 6.3, it seems I can't do that if the gesture recognizer is a constant. (This only seems to be a problem under the Xcode 6.3 beta The code allows me to set the pan gesture initializer after the call to `super.init(coder)`)

Since the variable is a required constant, it needs to be set up before I call the superclass `init(coder)`. However, the only initializer for a pan gesture recognizer takes self as a parameter. Self isn't available until after I've called `super.init(coder)`.

So, I can't create my gesture recognizer with a call to `UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:action:)` **before** the call to `super.init(coder)` because I need to pass self to that pan gesture initializer,

...and I can't call `UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:action:)` **AFTER** the call to `super.init(coder)`, because I have to set values for all required constants/variables before calling the superclass initializer.

The only solution I can come up with is to make my gesture recognizer an optional var, which I'd rather not do. It will always have a value after the initializer completes, and having to unwrap an optional every time I use it is annoying.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I did not test it to the end, but the compiler does not throw an error when doing this: let dragger = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

Comment: And then what? Add a target/action to the gesture recognizer after calling `super.init(coder)`? I guess that would work, but the docs for gesture recognizers say that `UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:action:)` is the designated initializer, and you're supposed to call the designated initializer.

Comment: Anything prevents you form making it a lazily computed property?

Comment: I could make it lazy, but my goal was to make it a required constant. lazy only works on var properties.

Comment: @Thomas, your solution of using the simple initializer of `UIPanGestureRecognizer()` and then adding a target/action after calling the superclass initializer is the only one I've found that lets me keep it as a required constant (let). Post your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solution of aahrens does not work (maybe because of a bug), here is what I would do, even if, as you pointed out, the docs say it's not the designated way:

In your init:

```
dragger = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
super.init(coder)
dragger.target = self
dragger.action = <actionHandler>
```

Comment: That's more or less what I ended up doing. (I used the method `addTarget(_, action:)`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do it make it implicitly unwrapped. Similar to how IBOutlets are decalred since in your case you know you're going to have a valid gesture configured. So I would declare it as

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let dragger: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        dragger = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "mySelector:")
    }
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't solve the catch-22 of having to assign it before calling the superclass initializer.

Comment: I wonder if that's a bug in Xcode 6.3. The code in my answer worked for me in Xcode 6.2

Comment: Apple's docs say they made the Swift spec more strict with 1.2. This might be an example of that, not a bug.